# Why is the following Prolog program only returning one solution?

Tags: prolog

```
contains(X, L) :- [X|_] = L.
contains(X, L) :- [Y|Z] = L, Y \= X, contains(X, Z).

f(R, L1, Res) :-
   (R,T) = X,
   contains(X, L1),
   Res = T.
```

`?- f(1, [(1,2), (1,3)], R).` gives only one value of R i.e. 2, but I expect it to return 2 values of R 2 and 3.

Answer to a similar [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog) question on stackoverflow.com recommends to use <kbd>SPACE</kbd>or <kbd>;</kbd> instead of <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, but I get `false` if I press <kbd>;</kbd> or <kbd>SPACE</kbd> after I get the first answer.

What is going wrong?

Comment: @WillNess I have updated the definition of `contains`. I forgot to include it, my bad.

Comment: @abhishek: your contains simply does not allow to recurse once it has found a member. Remove the `Y \= X`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem. Why not make your comment into an answer? I think you are spot-on...

Comment: @repeat: Willem's answer is kind-of-right but misleading. A `dif/2` in place of `(\=)/2` solves the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `contains/2` is defined as:

```
contains(X, L) :-
    [X|_] = L.
contains(X, L) :-
    [Y|Z] = L,
    Y \= X,
    contains(X, Z).
```

Your `Y \= X` (here in boldface) however prevents the `contains/2` to *recurse* on the *tail* `Z` once it has found an `X` that unifies with the head of the list. Indeed, in case `Y = X`, then `Y \= X` is false (since `Y \= X` is short for `\+ X = Y`). If `Y \= X` fails, we can not call `contains(X, Z)`, and therefore it can not check of other members of the list can be emitted.

So we can remove the statement and write:

```
contains(X, L) :-
    [X|_] = L.
contains(X, L) :-
    [Y|Z] = L,
    contains(X, Z).
```

and now `contains/2` will work like [**`member/2`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=member/2) works.

The code is however not very elegantly: you do unification in the body that can be done in the head. Furthermore we now have a variable `L` that is not used in the first clause, and a variable `Y` in the second clause that is not used. We can rewrite it to:

```
contains(X, [X|_]).
contains(X, [_|T]) :-
    contains(X, T).
```

and that's it. Now your `f/3` will work, although again it is not very elegant. We can rewrite this as well into:

```
f(R, L, T) :-
    contains((R,T), L).
```

and now our `f/3` predicate works in different directions:

```
?- f(1, [(1,2), (1,3)], R).
R = 2 ;
R = 3 ;
false.

?- f(X, [(1,2), (1,3)], 2).
X = 1 ;
false.

?- f(X, [(1,2), (1,3)], 3).
X = 1 ;
false.

?- f(X, L, 3).
L = [ (X, 3)|_G1262] ;
L = [_G1261, (X, 3)|_G1265] ;
L = [_G1261, _G1264, (X, 3)|_G1268] ;
L = [_G1261, _G1264, _G1267, (X, 3)|_G1271] .

?- f(1, L, 3).
L = [ (1, 3)|_G1250] ;
L = [_G1249, (1, 3)|_G1253] ;
L = [_G1249, _G1252, (1, 3)|_G1256] .
```

Comment: Your justification is incorrect: It's `(\=)/2` that was wrong, yes. But for a different reason: A `dif/2` in its stead works as expected.

Comment: @false. The simple replacement you’re proposing didn’t work when I tried it yesterday, most likely I made a typo and didn’t follow up. Now I just tried again and it works, so I second your opinion.

Comment: @false: because `\=` and `dif` have different semantics: `\=` fails if the two terms *can* be equal, whereas `dif` fails from the moment the two elements *are* equal.

Comment: @Willem: OP certainly intended to express inequality. And your description of `dif/2` is inaccurate: `dif/2` maintains inequality, whereas `(\=)/2` only approximates it.